# Why is my bottom border not restricting itself to the border of the Excel range?

Tags: c#, border, excel-interop

I've got this code to add a bottom border to a range:

```
var rowRngForHorBorder = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[4, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[4, 17]];
Excel.Borders _borders = rowRngForHorBorder.Borders;
_borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
_borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium;
```

This is what I want it to look like, more-or-less:

[image]

...and here is what it *does* look like:

[image]

Why are vertical lines scattered willy-nilly and/or helter-skelter along with the horizontal bottom? Who told them they could crash the spreadshet?

### UPDATE

It's still not working for me; with this updated code:

```
var rng = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[5, 1], _xlSheet.Cells[5, 17]];
Excel.Borders _borders = rng.Borders;
rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].ColorIndex = Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic;
_borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium;
```

...I see:

[image]

The code GrammatonCleric suggested seems pretty sensible, and that it *should* work...but it still doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so easy using SpreadsheetLight and OpenXML:

First, create a style:

```
sl = new SLDocument();
. . .
SLStyle styleBottomBorder = sl.CreateStyle();
styleBottomBorder.Border.BottomBorder.BorderStyle = BorderStyleValues.Thick;
styleBottomBorder.Border.BottomBorder.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Then apply it to a row:

```
sl.SetRowStyle(5, styleBottomBorder);
```

Much more intuitive than the Excel Interop way (which doesn't even work for me).

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this and the following worked for me...and should work for you:

```
    Excel.Range rng = workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[4, 1], workSheet.Cells[4, 17]];
    rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
    rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
    rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
    rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
    rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].ColorIndex = Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic;
    rng.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium;
```

It seems you have to style each element on it's own otherwise the Excel API thinks it should apply a full border around your range.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working for me; see the Update, if you please.

Answer (score 1):

Strange.

This is what my spreadsheet looks like:

[image]

Also, I'm using the following Excel.Interop reference:

[image]

This, coupled with the Border code I sent earlier works :)

Give it another bash?

Comment: I am using Version 15.0.0.0 (Runtime Version v2.0.50727; Name and Identity = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", Embed Interop Types == true, Specific Version = false, Aliases = global)

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you managed to get this working.

I would have suggested OpenXML.  I tried using it a couple of times in the past but was never able to achieve some of the things I could achieve using the Excel.Interop assembly, so I couldn't recommend it and take a gamble on whether or not it may or may not have worked for you.

Either way, glad it worked :)

Comment: After my experience with OpenXML and SpreadsheetLight yesterday, I am seriously considering refactoring my existing code to use that pair instead of Excel Interop. It definitely seems like a "no muss, no fuss" way of doing it. Or at least much less muss and fuss and cuss.